# Displaying table start from last array values[] in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, datatable

I want to sort table rows of the value array `[1][2][3]..etc` to be `..[3][2][1]` how to do it?

Below I attach my code please help to fix it.

```js
function showtbl() {
    var img = "<img src='logo/"
    var imgt = ".png'/>"
    var li = "<br /> Link: <a href='?apps="
    var lin = "'>http://playstore.co.id/?apps="
    var link = "</a><br /> Terbit: "
    var b = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='tampilss(&quot;"
    var bt = "&quot;);'>Screenshoot</button><br><button type='button' class='btn btn-success' onclick='tampilqr(&quot;"
    var btn = "&quot;);'>Download</button>"
    var A1 = "ss-clothes"
    var A2 = "korselindo"
    var A3 = "real-hiphop-shop"

    var values = new Array(3);
    values[1] = [img + A1 + imgt, A1 + li + A1 + lin + A1 + link, b + A1 + bt + A1 + btn];
    values[2] = [img + A2 + imgt, A2 + li + A2 + lin + A2 + link, b + A2 + bt + A2 + btn];
    values[3] = [img + A3 + imgt, A3 + li + A3 + lin + A3 + link, b + A3 + bt + A3 + btn];
    
    values.reverse(); // I has added this but values[3] is losing
  
    var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");

    // IE7 only supports appending rows to tbody
    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

    // for each outer array row
    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");

        // for each inner array cell
        // create td then text, append
        for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            var txt = document.createElement("span");
            txt.innerHTML = values[i][j];
            td.appendChild(txt);
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }

        // append row to table
        // IE7 requires append row to tbody, append tbody to table
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        myTable.appendChild(tbody);
    }

}

showtbl();
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Logo</th>
                <th>Nama App</th>
                <th>Tindakan</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
```

Above I attach my code please help to fix it.

I want to sort table rows of the value array `[1][2][3]..etc` to be `..[3][2][1]` how to do it?

Comment: User [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reverse) will be enough ?  Like: `values.reverse();`

Comment: I has added this but `values[3]` is losing

Comment: oh I had not noticed, array start from 0. new Array(3); have 0,1,2 index, not 1,2,3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use Array.prototype.reverse

```
var values = new Array(3);
values[1] = [img + A1 + imgt, A1 + li + A1 + lin + A1 + link, b + A1 + bt + A1 + btn];
values[2] = [img + A2 + imgt, A2 + li + A2 + lin + A2 + link, b + A2 + bt + A2 + btn];
values[3] = [img + A3 + imgt, A3 + li + A3 + lin + A3 + link, b + A3 + bt + A3 + btn];
values.reverse();
```

[Or you can modify the `for` loop so you loop through it in reverse](http://jsfiddle.net/zs73Lo3g/)

```
for (var i = values.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");

    // for each inner array cell
    // create td then text, append
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        var txt = document.createElement("span");
        txt.innerHTML = values[i][j];
        td.appendChild(txt);
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }

    // append row to table
    // IE7 requires append row to tbody, append tbody to table
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
    myTable.appendChild(tbody);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but so I lost all rows of tables @AnotherDev

Comment: I just added a link, check out the jsfiddle, is that what you're looking for?